# Multi Thread program debugging in eclipse and IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, intellij-idea

I am trying to switch from eclipse to IntelliJ and first thing I wanted to check was debugging Multi-Thread programs. I implemented a simple program written below.

```
class VolatileExample extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean running = true;
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        running = false;
    }

}

class Runner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        VolatileExample obj = new VolatileExample();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj);
        t1.start();
        **//**BREAKPOINT****
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.nextLine();
        obj.stopThread();
    }
}
```

Now when I debug this code in eclipse , **breakpoint I have commented in the program**, the main thread stays in suspended state while Thread executes and I get Hello running multiple times on the console
But as with IntelliJ, there is no output on the console, giving a view as if Thread is in suspended state.
Kindly help me with this debugging.I guess I am doing something wrong.

Comment: If you right click on a breakpoint in Idea, you'll find "stop all threads / stop current thread" setting. That might help.

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. It worked. I was not aware of this feature.